# What is the equivalent in Chinese for निताइ (Sanskrit)?

Tags: translation, classical-chinese, literary-chinese, middle-chinese

The **निताइ** Sanskrit Shape (English: Nitaai) is used to practice visualization based meditation with origins in ancient India.
[image]

Can someone kindly share the Chinese equivalent to be able to write Nitaai in Chinese yet be pronounced in the same manner. I tried Google translate but it changes the pronunciation of 't' to 'th' and 'Ni' to 'Nii'

Pronunciation Guide:
“Ni” in “Nitaai” is pronounced like “ni” in “omni”. “taai” is pronounced like “tie” but with a soft “t” like in Spanish, without curling our tongue like we do for pronouncing “t” in “tie” and instead pronouncing it by touching our straight tongue to the inside back of our top front teeth.

The below Nitaai Resonation track is the exact pronunciation for **निताइ**
[Resonating Nitaai Meditation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pW5MDY9oUnY)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a common word (for instance, there is no wikipedia page with that title or which include " निताइ " as an important part). What are the morphemes which make up the word? Perhaps other, more common words with those morphemes have already been transliterated into Chinese when Buddhism entered China.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: ni]
[image: taa]
[image: i]

The word is ni-taa-i in ITRANS notation.

The IAST notation is nitāi.

The meaning is to enter the nature or 進入自然／进入自然 in Chinese.

Answer (score 1):

People in Taiwan describe meditation with the term 冥想.

But it does not specifically refer to your practice, it is just a general term to refer to meditation.